# What would the path be?

Tags: javascript, xhtml, epub3

I have an iBooks EPUB3 book, with the following dir structure:

```
mimetype
META-INF (=dir)
OPS (=dir)
   scripts (=dir)
      jquery-2.1.1.min.js
      version.js
   Styles (=dir)
      stylesheet.css
   package.opf
   about.xhtml
```

etc.

Version.js contains:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.get ('package.opf',    <-- this correct? 
       function(xml) {
   $("span#datum").html($(xml).find("meta[property='dcterms\\:modified']").text());
   $("span#versie").html($(xml).find("meta[property='ibooks\\:version']").text());
   });
});
```

About.xhtml has the line

`<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/version.js"></script>`

in it's body,  to display the modification date and version number contained in package.opf. At least, that's the idea. But it does not.
Question 1: is the path for package.opf in version.js correct?

Question 2: is internal reading from the .opf file like this at all possible in an iBooks EPUB3 book?

Comment: Hmmm, after some more experimenting, I get the suspicion that "\\/OPS\\/package.opf" results in a deadlock / a continuous waiting for package.opf to become accessible. So: nice idea, but no dice.

Answer (score 0):

Great question.

Part 1: most likely, no: the path is no-longer correct. iBooks rips apart the ePub and puts things in it's own special places. You can see this in action with images by doing something like this:

```
$(".anImg").on("tap",function(){
    alert(event.target.src);
})
```

The function above will display something like this: "ibooksimg://BOOKID/Images/theImg.png". Due to the first part of this path (ibooksimg) I doubt the relative structure within your book is staying the same.

Part 2: Internal reading from ANY file in iBooks is something I believe to be impossible at this moment. I have never had any luck using GET requests or XHR from within iBooks: Apple has made this sort of in-file communication very difficult.

Suggestions: what we do is put all of our versioning info etc inside our JS documents as a json variable. Javascript files are the only type that seem to play nice with Apple (you can include them in your headers etc). It's a shame but better than nothing...